# Get name of the field when i change Model Backbone.Marionette

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette

I have a function which will get invoked each time when i make model change via modelEvents

```
myFunc(value) {
    var fieldName = ??;

    if(!value)
       this.model.unset(fieldName)
    }
}
```

the fieldName should be the name of the field which i changes? i really do not know how to get it. when model changes  i do not want a hard coded one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var changedAttribute = _.keys(this.model.changedAttributes())[0];
console.log( changedAttribute);`
 will return the list of attributes that are changed from last set.

[documentation link](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-changedAttributes)

Comment: i think you are trying to get the changed attribute , but now you are asking about model, can you clear me on this??

Comment: i mean particular model field ,i do not want list of attributes

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_.keys` + `changedAttributes`

```
myModel.on('change', function() {
    myFunc(_.keys(this.changedAttributes())[0]); 
})
```

In case of `modelEvents` can be used as following

```
modelEvents: {
    "change": function(){
        myFunc(_.keys(this.changedAttributes())[0]); 
    }
}
```

or

```
modelEvents: {
    "change": "onAnyModelChange"
},

onAnyModelChange: function() {
    myFunc(_.keys(this.changedAttributes())[0]); 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/smvtbkn1/1/

Comment: can i do like the following                                                       modelEvents : { "change:name"  : "myfunc"} , myFunc : function(){ var name = _.keys(this.changedAttributes());

Comment: It is failing here i am getting it as Undefined

Comment: no, it wont work as following, checkout updated answer